# C# SQL : update with params - getting 0 and without the text

Tags: c#, mysql, parameters, sql-update

I am making DatabaseManager class for my solution and I am getting the number 0 when I am trying to update the text.
For example : I have now the name michael and I wanted to change it to "michael , mike" so I'll probably use update.

```
public void AddCrime(CSteamID id, string crime, string time)
{
    try
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = createConnection();
        MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        crime = "," + crime;
        command.CommandText = "update `" + Main.Instance.Configuration.Instance.DatabaseTableName
          + "` set `crime` = crime + ( @crime ) where `steamId` = @steamID; select `crime` from `"
          + Main.Instance.Configuration.Instance.DatabaseTableName
          + "` where `steamId` = @steamID";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@steamID", id);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@crime", crime);
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
        AddTime(id, time);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Logger.Log(ex); }
}
```

How do I call it :

```
DatabaseManager.AddWanted(player.CSteamID, command[1], command[2]);
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Hi there, I'd like to see some more code around the code you've shown. Thank you!

Comment: type of database? odbc/oledb/database specific driver?

Comment: @RobLang Updated the code.

Comment: @bradbury9 I am using the xampp mysql server. I don't really know.

Comment: @marc_s It is parametrized, the only data concatenaded seems to be not user-defined, so looks pretty safe.

Comment: What is that CSteamID class instance that you pass inside the method. You cannot add it to the ID parameter as id. Do you mean id.SteadmID?

Comment: Hey @Steve. CSteamID class is the id for the player built by Steamworks api. the id is not the error I guess because I got it to string also at other classes.

Comment: Sorry but I have not much experience with Steamworks api. What is the result of _id.ToString()_ in your code above? Using AddWithValue is tricky

Comment: Example : 76561197960434622. But the error is with the @crime

Answer (score 1):

yor last sentence in your command is a select statement, `NonQuery` does not return values, only the number of rows affected. Change it to `ExecuteScalar` and store the value of the select in a variable.

Second error is the data type of the parameter `@steamID`. You set the value `id`, which is declares as `CSteamID id`... `CStreamId` is not `string`, change the `AddWithValue`

Comment: Nope, Still same bug.

Comment: You have two errors. a) store the value of the select statement `var crimeValue = command.ExecuteScalar();`

Comment: b) `CSteamID id` is not a data type MySQL could recognice. Change it to `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@steamID", id.ToString());` or `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@steamID", id.Int_or_string_property);`

Comment: It is. I am getting that to string. Already tried with steamid.

Comment: What happens if you run the statement on your db server directly?
Does that particular steamId exist in the table?
Where are you getting this "0" from, this is a void method and I see no functionality to read returned values.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, I added another method to get crime from table and then changed the void crime string to the current string + the table text.

> The error was : Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value.